# colspan and image not working

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

Help! I am pulling my hair out here.  I am trying to a) do a colspan in the first and third rows of this table, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I want both rows to span three columns, and b) I can't get the image to show and I have already done an extensive search online and have troubleshooted all the suggestions I found (image and page file in same folder, no coding errors...).  Any thoughts? Thanks! Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>table.htm</title> 
<style> table { width:90%; } 
td { width:33%; text-align:center; height:100px; } 
table { font-family:verdana, sans serif; text-align:center; }  
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<table>   
<tr bgcolor=“green”><td colspan=“3”><b>Table</b></td></tr>   
<tr><td>HTML coding</td><td><img src=“garlic.jpg” alt=“Garlic”></td>
<td>is fun</td></tr>   
<tr bgcolor=“#CCCCCC”><td colspan=“3”><i>Garlic</i></td></tr> 
</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Just a follow-up - thanks to everyone who commented on the colspan problem; it is now fixed!  However, still struggling with the image.  I have looked into curly vs. straight quote marks and I'm pretty sure these are straight, aren't they?  And if they're not, how do I find those?  I'm using TextEdit on my mac, which is very basic.  I've tried using a single quote mark instead and that didn't change anything.  Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, another update.  The image has been fixed, but I honestly don't understand why the first coding I did didn't work.  Does anyone have an explanation for me?  Thanks, if you do.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is actually your use of curling quotation marks around attribute values in your markup, which flat out doesn't work (here's the W3 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).  Change those to straight quotation marks (single or double), and you're in business ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this.  When I look at the quote marks, though, they look straight.  Do you have any experience using a basic text editor?  How would I indicate straight vs curly on a program like TextEdit (mac) for example?  And any thoughts on the image?

Comment: K, someone else has fixed the image.  But I'm not sure why my original coding didn't work.  Do you have any thoughts on that?  Thanks, if so.

Comment: Not sure about TextEdit, but in something like Microsoft word, it changes straight quotes to curly by default, so that might be worth watching out for. I can tell you that your original post definitely had curly quotes, so if you copied it from your actual code, you've got a problem. You could try looking for a free code editing tool online which would guarantee you don't run into this sort of problem (and help with code hints and broken links).

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5dm0gLkh/2/)

***UPDATE... nevermind...its definitely the quotes... i just did an updated jsfiddle in the comments****

The issue was you had quotes around colspan. You just need the number only.

```
  <table>   
  <tr bgcolor=“green”>
    <td colspan=3><b>Table</b></td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>HTML coding</td>
    <td><img src=“garlic.jpg” alt=“Garlic”></td>
    <td>is fun</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr bgcolor=“#CCCCCC”>
    <td colspan=3><i>Garlic</i></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: You answer contains the wrong quotes. Change those to straight quotes and add back the quotes that was wrong in OP's code.

Comment: ah... good point... i just copied and pasted into jsfiddle :)

Comment: here is the updated fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/5dm0gLkh/3/ ... by the way... whats the deal with that anyway... i just recently was looking into the differences.

Comment: That's so cool!  Thanks very much.  The colspan is now working!  Yay.  The image still isn't though.  Not sure what straight quotes are.  Will check it out.  Thanks again everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>table.htm</title> 
<style> table { width:100%; } 
td { text-align:center; height:100px; } 
table { font-family:verdana, sans serif; text-align:center; }  
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<table>   
<tr bgcolor=“green” >
   <td  colspan="3"><b>Table</b></td>
 </tr>   
<tr>
  <td>HTML coding</td>
  <td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNh8uaHeF_N7ObwLeNGBVAEIIh8l3qcSjcU2hPqvyR6-V4GEJk" alt="Garlic"></td>
  <td>is fun</td>
 </tr>   
<tr bgcolor=“#CCCCCC”>
  <td  colspan="3"><i>Garlic</i></td>
</tr> 
</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, it's perfect now!  Thanks so much! What did you do?  I also tried using a URL to link to a photo online and I couldn't get it to work!    ??

Comment: <img src=“garlic.jpg”> is not working.i think change your code.
<img src="garlic.jpg">  - change **“** to **"**